# Period of a finite binary sequence

Tags: binary, sequence, cycle

Let `G` be a generator that on each invocation yields a bit of a binary sequence of length N. Generator wraps around N, so invocation `k` returns the same result as `k%N`. What's the best way to check if the sequence has a period smaller than N? Assume N is too big to factor.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.  I think it belongs on math SO.  Google for "random number generator diehard test" to see a good way to test your generator.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests